# What does the sentence "... not available for aspects declared in the @Aspect model" in spring doc mean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

From section [5.4.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts) in spring doc we can see the note

> The bean PCD is supported only in Spring AOP and not in native AspectJ weaving. It is a Spring-specific extension to the standard PCDs that AspectJ defines and is, therefore, not available for aspects declared in the @Aspect model.

It says that bean PCD not available for aspects declared in the @Aspect model. I don't understand it because we can use the bean designator like

```cpp
@Aspect
public class MyPointcuts{
    @Pointcut("bean(*Service)")
    public void businessService() {}
}
```

What does it actually mean?

Comment: It means what it states. The `bean` expression is only available when aspectj aspects are defined and used in a Spring context. When using plain Aspectj aspect (without spring) then it isn't available as a `bean` is nothing outside of Spring. Or differently put it will only work with the Spring Based AOP using Proxies, when you use loadtime or compile timeweaving it will not work and give an error.

Comment: I misunderstand it because of my poor English. Thanks a lot. @M.Deinum